# refactoring static member functions with same parameters

Tags: c++, class, static-methods

I have a static helper class, which has several functions that are using same parameters:

```
class helper {
public:
  static double getValue(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
private:
  static double foo(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
  static bool bar(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
  static bool qux(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
  static double wad(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
  static int xyz(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ... );
};
```

use it like:

```
double value = helper::getValue(a, b, c, k, ...);
```

`getValue()` will call `foo()`, which will call `bar()`, `qux()` and `wad()`, etc.
They all need the same data set of a, b, c.

As you can see, there are many duplicated parameters that looks a little messy.

Is there any way to refactor it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create a class/struct `Params` that contains all the parameters as members. Have your static function accept an instance of `Params` instead of all your parameters. Your code will look like:

```
struct Params {
  const CString &a;
  const CString &b;
  const CString &c;
   ...
}

class helper {
public:
  static double getValue(const Params & p);
private:
  static double foo(const Params & p);
  static bool bar(const Params & p);
  static bool qux(const Params & p);
  static double wad(const Params & p);
  static int xyz(const Params & p);
};
```

This way you only have to create a `Params` object once and pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

*One* possible solution could be to have `getValue` return an internal class instance, which can be converted to a `double`.

Something like this:

```
class helper
{
public:
    class helper_internal_class
    {
        friend class helper;

    public:
        operator double() const
        {
            return foo();
        }

    private:
        helper_internal_class(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ...)
            : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c), ...
        {}

        CString a_;
        CString b_;
        CString c_;
        ...

        double foo() const;
        {
            // Do something more...
            return bar();
        }
        double bar() const;
        ...
    };

    static helper_internal_class getValue(const CString &a, const CString &b, const CString &c, ...)
    {
        return helper_internal_class(a, b, c, ...);
    }
};
```

It's a little more boilerplate, but at least you don't have to pass the arguments around all the time.

If it's *better*? That's up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with functions with variable argument lists, there is no way to do this directly. You cannot pass a variable argument list to another function with a variable argument list.

Instead you can declare a function with a parameter of type va_list, use va_start and va_end in the functions with variable argument list to create a va_list, and pass it to the helper function.